# Should I use "if" or "while" in this code ? into a heap

Tags: java, insert, heap

Consider the part here, should I use if or while to insert a new key into a heap. So I can compare parent and their child, if if child is larger, I can swap it to parent. It should be efficiency too.

```
public void insert(Student newS)
   {
       students.add(newS); //add new student
       int index = size()-1; //last index
       int parent =(index); 

       while(newS.gpa() > students.get(parent).gpa()); // gpa of new student > gpa of parent. 
       {
           swap(parent, index);
           index = parent;
           parent = parent(index);    
       }
}
```

Should I use If instead of while? Which one is better? While can go through the arraylist and pick the larger one, and replace it to the parent.

Comment: Your question is "should I use 'if' or the infinite loop I wrote?" ... really? Do you know that they have different purposes? Their usage depends on your goal.

Comment: I just explain more in the comment below, please help. Thanks

Comment: @Tom That isn't necessarily an infinite loop. If `parent(root)` returns `root`, then the loop will terminate. Admittedly, it would be more clear if he wrote `while (index > root && ...)`

Comment: @JimMischel It doesn't matter what `parent(root)` will return, that code block will only be reached ___after___ the loop terminates.

Comment: @Tom: I see the semicolon now.

Answer (score 2):

They are two very different things.

An if statement checks if an expression is true, or false, and then runs the code inside the statement. The code is run once.

A while statement is a loop. It continues to execute the code in the statement as long as the expression is true.

It's hard to compare the pros/cons of the two, since they do two separate things.

Comment: for example, I have arraylist GPA of student, (3.2, 3.1, 3.0, 2.6, 2.3, 2.5, 2.2 ) if I want to insert 3.4 to index 3, I need to compare it with 2.6, then compare it to grandparent, until it becomes to the top of the root. That's heap binary, so the parent must be larger than the child. I think I should use while to compare everything in the

Comment: @FZ-07 Of course you need a `while`: you need to do something potentially many times: as long as (while) a condition remains true.